# Kafka key actors

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to pin point key actors from Kafka world, with definitions as simple as possible in order to have a correct high-level overview.

Hope it helps others, or help me in case I get something wrong, and someone tells me.

## Kafka controller broker

**Server side**

**At Kafka cluster level**

It is responsible for managing states of partitions and replicas, plus to perform administrative tasks like re-assigning partitions.
For example, Zookeeper is used to detect Kafka broker failures and signal them to Kafka controller broker to trigger a rebalance.

## Kafka partition leader

**Server side**

**At partition level**

Each partition in Kafka has a single leader and 0-N followers.
It handles all read/writes for a certain partition.

## Group coordinator

**Server side**

**At consumer group**

Kafka broker that receives heartbeats from all the consumers in a consumer group. It can issue a rebalance by informing Kafka controller broker as soon as a consumer has disappeared.

## Offset manager broker

**Server side**

**At consumer group level**

Stores all the offsets for a given consumer group. 
Not clear here if this broker is the same as the group coordinator broker...

## Consumer group leader

**Client side**

**At consumer group level**

One of the consumers which help at partition assignment.

Please let me know in case I've written something false.

Thanks,

Cristi